# Is it possible to use the Share Intent on Arrays

Tags: java, android

I would like to use the share intent on my array. I created an array that features both an image and text. However, is it possible to share the array?

I tried the image share intent and it did not work. Basically, the user clicks on the button and it shares the image and text combined. I used the onclick listener for the button. Is it possible to share the array or do I need to share the individual image and text? The image comes with a particular set of text and I randomized it using shuffle

Here is the code for the Java main creating of variable

```
private ImageView mImageView;
private TextView mTextView;
private Button mButton;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    btnShare = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShare);

    mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.facts);
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    showRandomFacts();

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showRandomFacts();

        }
    });
```

And here is the Array in Main Java activity

public void showRandomFacts() {

```
    shuffleFacts();
    mImageView.setImageResource(factArray[0].getmImage());
    mTextView.setText(factArray[0].getmFact());


}




Facts f01 = new Facts(R.drawable.bigpen, "Owls can swivel their heads up to 200 degrees");
Facts f02 = new Facts(R.drawable.blunt, "Blunts was first derived by food");
Facts f03 = new Facts(R.drawable.cake, "fsefs");

Facts [] factArray = new Facts[] {

        f01,f02,f03

};


public void shuffleFacts() {

    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(factArray));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to implement the parcelable in your Facts class (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable).

This allows you to share any class object in an intent.
When you implemented the interface you can create an new intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
Facts f01 = new Facts(R.drawable. , "Random fact")
intent.putExtra("f01", f01);
startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve the object in the next activity you use:

```
Facts f01= getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("f01");
```